# Putting HTML within a <p> without it becoming elements

Tags: html

I want to put in some code within a paragraph without the browser thinking it's code meant for the page. How can I do that?

The code is below. I want the contents with one asterix to be displayed as text, whereas the lines with two asterixes are supposed to be a real paragraph.

```
**<p>**
*<html>
<head>
<p> Hi </p>*
**</p>**
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to replace your HTML tag chatacters (`<` and `>`) with their corresponding entities (`&lt;` and `&gt;`).

Comment: Incidentally, [Asterix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix) is (a character in) a comic book series. The symbol * is an asterisk.

Comment: Try to use `<pre>`